# How to unblock font awesome icons on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have used a theme on wordpress named "SATINE" and I have finished my website but I have a problem that I have not face it yet. This theme is using FontAwesome icons in some places that are configured via widgets section. The problem is that that FontAwesome Icons are not showing on the website. Instead of icons there are replaced with squares like here (Printscreen: http://prntscr.com/j4znsc). I checked my error logs on Plesk and I found this ( Printscreen: http://prntscr.com/j4zoae). I think that It has to do with SSL and with the file .htaccess but I cannot configure it right. I am pasting my .htaccess file here so you can see what its written inside and help me or give me a hint. 
    # BEGIN WordPress

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Can anyone help me or does anyone have already faced the same problem with me?
I think it has to do with this line:

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

but I dont know how to configure it right.
Thank you,
Best regards

Comment: Any errors in your browser console?

Comment: @AndrewSchultz Yes check it: http://prntscr.com/j553x3

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file located? Is it in the root of the WordPress installation?

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is incorrect, try this with the leading forward slash.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>    
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|ttf|otf|woff)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: What happens if you don't use the FileMatch and just write have Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" ?

Comment: @RafailMavrogordatos I changed my answer to add the $ anchor to tell regex to look at the end of the string.  Also, what version of Apache are you using?  Is it managed or self managed hosting?  You might need to restart the Apache server.

Comment: I have a plesk web host edition. I have a reseller package but not root access. Any hint?

Comment: Can you describe me the exact form that should be mixed with the WordPress typicall htaccess file?

Comment: Try using Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" without the FileMatch conditional.

Comment: I tried but nothing. Is there any way so I can do it?